# Python-Less than/ greater than value returns

Tags: python, syntax

I want to show that between the two values entered by the user, one of them is the greater value. When I run the program, it tells me i have "invalid syntax" on line 3:

```
def main():
    num1 = int(input('Enter the first integer: ')
    num2 = int(input('Enter the second integer: ')


    print('The greater integer is ' result)

    def maximum(num1, num2):
        if num1 > num2:
            return result = num1
        else:
            return result = num2

main()
```

Comment: You have more left parentheses than right parentheses.  Parenthesis must balance.

Comment: Your code is a bit of a mess. You need to move maximum to it's own function (right now you have it nested in main.) When returning use just "return num1" for example.

Comment: Apologies, still pretty new to this so stupid mistakes are still cropping up. Fixed and got it all sorted. thanks for the input guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change your code to this:

```
def main():
    num1= int(input('Enter the first integer: '))
    num2 = int(input('Enter the second integer: '))
    def maximum(num1, num2):
        if num1 > num2:
            return num1
        else:
            return num2
    print('The greater integer is ', maximum(num1, num2))

main()
```

There were a couple of errors:

**1.** Not enough parenthesis in your input statements

**2.** You were not calling your method `maximum(...)`, also you have to declare it before using it.

**3.** You forgot a comma in your `print` statement

You can also declare the `maximum(...)` method outside the `main()`:

```
def maximum(num1, num2):
    if num1 > num2:
        return num1
    else:
        return num2

def main():
    num1= int(input('Enter the first integer: '))
    num2 = int(input('Enter the second integer: '))        
    print('The greater integer is ', maximum(num1, num2))

main()
```

Comment: This worked mostly. I had to move "print" into the main function for it to work properly on my end. Thanks! :)

Comment: It's actually in the main method. Note indention.

Comment: You can also put the `maximum` method outside the `main` method.

Comment: sorry, that's what I meant. suppose it works both ways? Thanks again!